# LTR to RTL dynamically in core php project

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website written in core php ,  I want to add Arabic language . So i have to make LTR to RTL dynamically . But how can  I do it ? do i have to change all css code and rewrtie them all for RTL or is there anythins else ?  I searched a lot and found rtlcss but how can i implement them easily ?

Comment: i don't think it needs rewriting all css code but you will need some altered. i usually include a main css file which is LTR and if the user chose RTL page i append after the main css file another css which is RTL modification and that file will override the css file before it

Comment: by override i mean it will override selectors in common between the two files

Comment: can you give any sample of code/example to understand better ?

Comment: sure just let me write it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

all of the following code is pure examples and will be shortened

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.min.css">
        <!-- this should be included if the user's language is RTL -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/rtl.min.css">
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

#### main.min.css

```css
/* here goes all css codes that goes with all pages */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
div.tab-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.main-panel {
    float: right;
}
```

#### rtl.min.css

```css
/* this will override the previous css rule */
.main-panel {
    float: left;
}
body {
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 0;
}
```

you can also join them together in one file and in your php file add class to body `.rtl`
and in your css file ( of course at the end ) add css rules like:

```css
body.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

but for sake of lighter css files and since many users will not benefit from the RTL rules i would advise using the first example

Answer (score 0):

there is some online converter to transform ltr based css code to rtl based css code . Then i added different css for different choice of user . SO there will be two css file .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using [enter link description here](https://rtlcss.com) ltr to rtl css converter. Then I added differenct css for different logic which comes from database. 
Let me give an example , 
I stored a value in my database ,
 direction = 'ltr'/'rtl' . So in my frontend , inside header tag I added different css based on the direction value . Hope this logic will be helpful